# My template files are not in system > expressionengine > templates. How can I figure out where they are?

Tags: templates

My template files are not in system > expressionengine > templates. There's only a single index.html file in that folder.

I visited Design ‣ Templates ‣ Global Preferences. Basepath to Template File Directory is set to a single slash.

How can I figure out where they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates are saved on database, by default.

If you want to save them as files, you need to enable this feature on [Design > Templates > Global Preferences > Save Templates as Files](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html). Their default location is the folder of your website and "system/expressionengine/templates", if you don't changed the name of the system folder. You can change the directory where they are saved on [Design > Templates > Global Preferences > Basepath to template directoy](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html). You need to fill this field with the full server path.

If you already have templates on database, you can edit them on Design > Template Manager > Template Group > Template name. You'll find a check box "Save template as file".

The template as files and on database can be synchronized on [Design › Templates › Synchronize Templates](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/synchronize_templates.html).

Some developers synchronize the templates, disable the feature of saving the files and delete them before launch the website.

You can read about saving your templates as files on [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/templates_as_files.html).